# Find text in NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have several custom objects in an NSArray, I need to search through all the objects and fnd the index of the object that has a property which matches a string.
Should I be using a for each loop? I need it to be relatively fast to search each time a new character is entered in a textfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSPredicate` is neat, but overkill (and it won't give you the index of the found object; just the object itself).

The paired array approach, which will work, feels odd to me (probably because it's using a paired array).

I would either use a `for()` loop (and `break;` when I found what I was looking for), or use a block enumerator:

```
__block NSInteger indexOfMatchingObject = NSNotFound;
[myArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
  if ([[obj property] doesWhatImLookingFor]) {
    indexOfMatchingObject = idx;
    *stop = YES;
  }
}];
```

Or a slightly different variant:

```
NSInteger indexOfMatchingObject = [myArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
  return ([[obj property] doesWhatImLookingFor]);
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can cache the property values in an array:

```
NSArray *propertyValues = [myObjects valueForKey:@"someProperty"];
```

And then you can quickly find the index of the object whose `someProperty` equals to the value you are searching for:

```
NSUInteger objectIndex = [propertyValues indexOfObject:propertyValue];
```

Alternatively, you can search with NSPredicate (should be noticeably slower) or using a for loop (should be a tiny bit slower).

If you can sort your objects by property values, you can optimize the for loop for the case when the value is not found by an average of 2 times.

Comment: you think a `for` loop would be slower than the `valueForKey:` approach?  With yours, you have to build an array of every object's property, and then call `indexOfObject:` on it.  This is a worst-case O(2N) approach.  With a `for` loop, you only have to iterate the array once.  In other words, a `for` loop should be twice as fast as what you've proposed (granted, if the array is small, the difference will probably be negligible).

Comment: @Dave DeLong I hope the results of `valueForKey:` can be cached in advance so you can use whatever optimizations `indexOfObject:` may have. I admit I didn't even try to check actual performance, though.

Answer (score 1):

Looping through is obviously a way, but use of predicates might also work for.

```
- (NSArray *)filteredArrayUsingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop, and remember to `break` after you find a match.

Answer (score 0):

I'd either use a predicate to filter the array or you could enumerate though and inspect the objects. I made this category add on to NSArray [in my framework](https://github.com/Machx/Zangetsu/blob/master/Source/NSArrayAdditions.m#L77) so that I could inspect each object in a block and return it when I found what I was looking for.

```
-(id)cw_findWithBlock:(BOOL (^)(id obj))block
{
    for(id obj in self){
        if(block(obj)){
            return obj;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

You could easily do the same type of thing but return the index instead.